# Cider molding and wont go away but not getting worse?

Tags: fermentation, cider, mold

I have three ciders going, two "spiced" ciders and one regular/standard whatever the straight apple squeezed cider ("Ryan's" brand if anyone is familiar) is called. This is my first attempt at cider, didn't do much research just got a great deal on cider.

**QUESTION:**

Is my cider done for? can I rack it off the mold? is it safe to drink? what can I do?

**HERE'S THE SIMPLE STORY:**

The cider was on sale because it was close to "sell by" date but not expired yet, when I opened the half gallon jugs a couple of them had small chunks of mold on them. Because I had high hopes I just picked out the mold and dumped it in assuming the yeast would kick out some alcohol and protect it from any mold.

**DETAILS:**

Well I would be writing if that were the case, one started molding right away ("spiced" on Lalvin D47 (Dry wine yeast)) o.g. was 1.052 and currently is 1.002, smells very moldy but looks very clear. when poured into graduated cylinder it appeared to be carbonated I would say around 3 volumes (yes airlock was used). the mold covers about half surface area, and is thin and white (Thicker and white then a Pellicle)
The second was a non-"spiced" on the same yeast, and it only has what I would describe as a pre-mold coagulated chunk 1" by 3" (very small in comparison) o.g. was 1.056 now is 1.002. small hint of mold smell but mostly spice cider smell.
The third is a "spiced" cider on 100% Brett B, this one was the last to mold but has a slightly thicker mold and also blue and white and covers an area about 2" by 2". This one also cleared out very well but has zero attenuation, started at 1.052 and is currently the same.

**FERMENTATION:**
(all three fermented in the same conditions and in glass) started fermentation around the low 60's for about two weeks then moved into an area 68-70 deg for the remaining week and a half.

Comment: Was this cider supposed to be pasteurized? If so, why in the world would it have mold in it when you opened it up? This would scare me off of using it for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to dump all three batches. It could be that the mold is non-toxic, but I personally would not be willing to take that chance. Besides, it's probably going to taste dreadful.

For future reference, if you suspect your juice is not entirely fresh, you can add sulphite at the rate of 1 campden tablet per gallon. This will knock back microbial activity and give your cultured yeast a chance to flourish. Pitch the yeast 24 hours after adding the sulphite.

That being said, since mold was visible when you pitched your yeast I suspect there was almost no chance of this cider turning out other than it did.

Comment: Ya know when you know the right thing to do and you just dont want to admit it? Thank you I really just needed the reaffirming nudge!!! (Batches dumped)